# Why i have to redefinition the int main

Tags: c++, integer, program-entry-point

I have this code. write a code that asks for a number and define 2 functions. the first must return the remainder of the number by dividing by 7 and the second must return the day of the week (0 =Sunday 1=Monday .. 6=Saturday). so far i have done this:

BUT when i run it , it gives me this error --> redefinition of 'int main()'
what does this mean and what do i have to fix?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myNumbers(int a)
{
    return a % 7;
}
void myFuction(string);
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "give a number between 0-6: \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "the result is " << myNumbers(a);
}

int main()
{
    myFuction("sunday"};
    myFuction("monday"};
    myFuction("tuesday"};
    myFuction("thursady"};
    myFuction("wendsday"};
    myFuction("friday"};
    myFuction("saturday"};
    return 0;

    cout << "then day is:" << myFunction();
}
```

Comment: You have two functions called `main`. That's not allowed.

Comment: `myFuction("sunday"}`. `}` doesn't close `(`.

Comment: thank u for the } .

Comment: @Bathsheba what should i change in what? i cannot fix it.. i tryied a few things but i still have errors with this code.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare 2 `main` functions, because this will confuse the compiler about which one to run as `main` method.  In order to fix the error, you should rename or delete one of them. You should have better defined methods outside of `main`.

Comment: i knew there was a problem with main but i wasnt sure so now how can i called it ?

Comment: No need to call main. Compiler does so itself.

Comment: so i just delete the second "int main()" and the code will run ?

Comment: In addition you should declare myFunction body then there you go.

Comment: i tryied to change something in the code but i cannot understand what should i declare where and what..i am still new but i wasnt able to fix it so far..

Comment: i have understood that the compilier cannot run this code due to the headnames. BUT what do i rename?